# Next.js 13+ static export redirects to / or home in deployed environment, but not locally, when refreshing

Tags: next.js, static, next.js13

Next.js 13+ redirects to / or home in deployed environment, but not locally, when refreshing.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

For example:

If i refresh mysite.com/aboutus , it takes me to mysite.com in our test environment on the deployed site.

Some components are server side rendered, some are client side rendered.

If I am running localhost:3000/aboutus

The url remains at the top mysite.com/aboutus, but the site is displaying the mysite.com (home page).

Edit: If I add `trailingSlash: true` it brings me to
`https://example.com:5000/aboutus/` and is broken obviously.
So my assumption is the page is getting cached to the server at some point?

I'm using nginx deployed in openshift.

nginx conf file:

```
# Set worker processes based on your CPU cores, nginx does not benefit from setting more than that
worker_processes auto;

# Load perl module for env var subsitution
load_module modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so;

# read in env variable
env runtimeEnvironment;
env applicationName;

# number of file descriptors used for nginx
# the limit for the maximum FDs on the server is usually set by the OS.
# if you don't set FD's then OS settings will be used which is by default 2000
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

# change pid loc for lower privileged account
pid        /tmp/nginx.pid;

# Log errors/emerg/crit to syslog (splunk)
# Log crit events to local container output
error_log syslog:server=splunk-dmz.nvthbs.local:21514 error;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

# provides the configuration file context in which the directives that affect connection processing are specified.
events {
    # determines how many clients will be served per worker
    # max clients = worker_connections * worker_processes
    # max clients is also limited by the number of socket connections available on the system (~64k)
    worker_connections 4000;

    # optimization to serve multiple clients per thread
    use epoll;

    # enable multiple connections
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    # set env vars
    perl_set $runtimeenv 'sub { return $ENV{"runtimeEnvironment"};}';
    perl_set $appName 'sub { return $ENV{"applicationName"};}';

    # limit the number of connections per single IP - DDOS Protection
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;

    # limit the number of requests for a given session - DDOS Protection
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=200r/s;

    # if the request body size is more than the buffer size, then the entire (or partial)
    # request body is written into a temporary file
    # affects any POST actions sent to nginx
    client_body_buffer_size  128k;

    # buffer size for reading client request header
    client_header_buffer_size 10K;

    # maximum number and size of buffers for large headers to read from client request
    large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;

    # time a server will wait for client header to be sent after request
    client_header_timeout 12;

    # time a server will wait for client body to be sent after request
    client_body_timeout 12;

    # timeout for keep-alive connections to client
    keepalive_timeout 30;

    # timeout between two reads - keeps memory free -- default 60
    send_timeout 10;

    # set log format for access logs
    log_format  custom 'Application:$appname Environment:$runtimeenv '
                              '- $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                                 '"$http_x_forwarded_for" $request_id ';
    
    # Condition map to reduce access logging and eliminate 200 / 300
    map $status $loggable {
        ~^[23]  0;
        default 1;
    }

    # Access log configuration with conditional statement applied to reduce logging events
    # access_log syslog:server=splunk-dmz.nvthbs.local:21514,facility=local7,tag=nginx custom if=$loggable;

    # access logging all events
    access_log syslog:server=splunk-dmz.nvthbs.local:21514,facility=local7,tag=nginx custom;

    # copies data between one FD and other from within the kernel
    # faster than read() + write()
    sendfile on;

    # send headers in one piece - more performant
    tcp_nopush on;

    # don't buffer data sent, good for small data bursts in real time
    tcp_nodelay on;

    # enable gzip compression
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable msie6;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types
        # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
        text/css
        text/javascript
        text/xml
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        application/atom+xml
        font/truetype
        font/opentype
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        image/svg+xml;

    # allow the server to close connection on non responding client, this will free up memory
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    # number of requests client can make over keep-alive
    # having high value can be especially beneficial in testing load generation
    # Consider evaluating for production
    keepalive_requests 100000;

    # Set temp paths - need to be explicitly set to /tmp due to permissions
    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;
    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

  server {
    # zone which we want to limit by upper values, we want limit whole server
      limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 10;
      limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=10 nodelay;

      listen 8080;
      listen 5000 ssl;
      ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/crt/tls.crt; 
      ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/key/tls.key;
      ssl_protocols     TLSv1.2;

      default_type application/octet-stream;

      root /usr/share/nginx/apps;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store';
        # proxy_pass https://mysite.site.com:5000;
        # proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }

      #test
      #test

       # To allow POST on static pages
        error_page  405     =200 $uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a possible mis configured web server. The local webserver passes the path info to what amounts to the Single Page App and so it works just fine. It seems there may be something missing from your webserver configuration. How are you hosting it?

Comment: @Chase nginx on openshift via docker. I will update with nginx conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the nginx implementation.

An additional line for '$uri.html' is needed in order to find the .html files.

in nginx.conf:

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /index.html;
  }
```

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10522#discussioncomment-884013